# Couldn't find child window using FindWindowExA()

Tags: c++, winapi

Trying to get button's handle on window calculator's form.
Spy++ shows the following tree:

("Calculator"; CalcFrame) ->

(""; CalcFrame) ->

(""; #32770 Dialog), ...anather child windows ->

(""; Button) ,... another child windows

*// ("window caption";  window class)
// ->  next child level*

I catch main window and go deeper using FindWindowExA();

```
#define wndName "Calculator"
...
    HWND calcHwnd = ::FindWindowA(0, wndName);
    HWND frameHwnd = ::FindWindowExA(calcHwnd, 0, 0, 0);
    HWND contentHwnd = ::FindWindowExA(calcHwnd, 0, "#32770 (Dialog)", 0);
    DWORD er = GetLastError();
```

I could use ::FindWindowExA(calcHwnd, 0, 0, 0) several times to get the HWND I need(at that level there are several child windows). but i want to get HWND using condition that the window i need has class "#32770 (Dialog)".
But ::FindWindowExA(calcHwnd, 0, "#32770 (Dialog)", 0) - returns NULL. GetLastError returns 0. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#32770` is actually a class atom. Try:

```
HWND contentHwnd = ::FindWindowExA(calcHwnd, NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(32770), NULL);
```